# Jax-WS class ... nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I found some similar threads, but none were of much help.
The thing is the following. I have a jar which contains a data holder class, Foo. In another jar I have a JAX web service, which returns a list of Foos:

```
@WebMethod
public List<Foo> getFooInfo(List<Long> numbers, String content) {
 return fooProvider.getFooInfo(numbers, content);
}
```

Aaand to make it a bit more complex, the FooProvider class is contained in another jar.
I get the following exception: 
Class ...Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context

I tried adding `@XmlSeeAlso(Foo.class)` to the web service class. Also added it to the FooProvider, but didn't help.

Any suggestions I could try?

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: What is the application server?

Comment: I have the same problem on a JBoss 5.1.0 GA application server